# jquery ajax call is inserting slashes in my HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am loading html data via ajax and it is putting slashes in the html like this:

> https://xxx.cloudfront.net/bucket/12345.jpg\"   width=\"320\"
>   height=\"319\" />

And here is the script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    //helper method to get querystring values
    var qs = new String(window.location.search.substring(1));
    var characterID = getFromQueryStringValues(qs, "characterID");

    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/characterData/' + characterID,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#characterContent").html(data);
        },
        fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Is there anyway to get this script from doing this?

thanks!

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Your URL example shows `/bucket` but your code shows `/api/characterData/`. The answer, however, is the same; you must escape URL data. Try using `encodeURIComponent` for the `characterID` variable.

Comment: thanks @MikeMcCaughan . The ajax url points to a web api controller while the html that it spits out includes images from an image repository.  Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the answer, I'll go test right now.

Comment: are you sure the api is returning html and not json? Those slashes are not put in by the ajax script and would be set server side